# django Meta class Fields and relation with database

Tags: django

I am a beginner in Django and I'm having difficulty in understanding the  Meta class which is written inside another class
 I hope someone can help me understand it more clearly

```
 class UserRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
        email=forms.EmailField()

        class Meta:
            model=User
            fields=['username','email','password1','password2']
```

What are Meta fields and how is Meta class related to database? Why is this Meta class used here?

Comment: It's just metadata for your form so if it does have then Django will use it to create correspond `fields` as your `models` in your Form. In Django Form, it not directly work with database but it does via `model` and with these fields when you create a form and call `.save` function, Django Form will use your `model` to create an instance follow your `fields` and then store to the database.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create a form in which new users will enter username, email, and password to create their user. What do you need to do? You have to tell how you form should behave. As an example, you should define how the form treats if the user is entering an invalid email or if he or she is entering two unequal passwords in the passwords field. More importantly, you need to define what fields you want. Well, an easy way to do all this is using the characteristics of an already available model, that is the User model. In meta, you are telling the form from which model it should learn its behavior and what fields of the model it should include in itself. Note that you might override some parts of the behaviour as you have done in `email=forms.EmailField()`